# Python 3.5 - Difference between '//' and 'int()'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/ALEXTASK) problem in python 3.5. Here is my solution code:

```
def gcd(a, b):
if b == 0:
    return a
return gcd(b, a % b)

def lcm(a, b):
    return int((a*b)/gcd(a,b))

def core():
    N = int(input())
    nums = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    ans = lcm(nums[0], nums[1])
    for i in range(0, N):
        for j in range(i+1, N):
            ans = min(ans, int(lcm(nums[i], nums[j])))
    return int(ans)

for t in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
    print(core())
```

It was giving me Wrong Answer for subtask 3. After hours of hair pulling i found that changing the line

```
return int((a*b)/gcd(a,b))
```

in lcm function to

```
return (a*b)//gcd(a,b)
```

solved the problem. This got me curious. I always thought that int() and floor() functions are exactly same for positive integers. Since we are sure that numerators and denominators will always be positive, why is this difference seen here?
Any sample test case where `int((a*b)/gcd(a,b))` would be different from `a*b//gcd(a,b)` given a,b are positive integers?

**Update:**
Sample test case where int(a/b) is different from a//b: 250263628386554294 1.

For explanation [see this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: Yes but `int()` rounds the operand, `//` truncates the result.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: No, `int` rounds towards 0 and `//` floors.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: That is not true.  `int(9/10)` is `0`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried print(int(1.6)) and print(int(1.4)). Both print 1. How is int() rounding the operand?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example that actually demonstrates that it fails with the `int` and works with the `//`?

Comment: @BrenBarn if i knew such example i wouldnt have asked what i asked. I am getting WrongAnswer in codechef submission. I cant see their test case against which this is failing.

Comment: @Ansh43: Try forgetting about codechef temporarily and write your own code and test it with your own values until *you* find a case where it works with `int` but fails with `//`.

Comment: Yeah, I meant round down. Thanks.

Comment: @BrenBarn you can see my last two submissions here  [link]https://www.codechef.com/status/ALEXTASK,anshtanwar43 to see that the one with int() is not accepted as 100 pts answer while the one with // is.

Comment: May i know reason for downvotes...

Comment: @user2357112 I meant round down, thanks. By the way, what’s the difference between rounding to 0 and flooring?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Flooring is toward the negative direction. floor(-0.5) is -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding of the math seems fine, but what you're missing is that `/` produces a floating-point result, and floating-point numbers have limited precision:

```
>>> x = 2**64-1
>>> x
18446744073709551615
>>> int(x / 1)
18446744073709551616
```

Even dividing by 1 can lose precision. In contrast, dividing two ints with `//` works entirely in integer arithmetic, without a floating-point intermediate result and without losing precision.